# Django block content not working properly

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I have a `base.html` file with the following code:

```
{% load static %}
{% load custom_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
        
    <body>
        <style>
            html {
                scroll-behavior: smooth;
            }
            *,
            body {
                margin: 0;
            }
            body {
                display:flex; flex-direction:row;
                background: #030914;
                background: url('/static/dashimages/map.svg'), #030914;;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                overflow-y:scroll;
            }
            .nav-container {
                width: 200px;
                padding: 20px;
                position: fixed;
               top: 0;
               left: 0;
               height: 100%;
               max-height: 100vh;
               border-right:  2px solid rgba(33, 40, 54, 0.5);
               overflow: hidden;
               padding-top: 35px;
              }
            .nav-links {
                display:flex;
                flex-direction:column;
                justify-content:center;
                align-items:center;
                gap: 25px;
                margin-top: 30px;
            }
            .nav-link {
                display:flex;
                flex-direction:row;
                justify-content: flex-start;
                width: 110%;
                padding: 14px 20px;
                gap: 20px;
               transform: rotate(5deg);
            }
            .nav-link:hover {
                cursor: pointer;

            }
            .nav-link a {
                font-family: 'Poppins';
                font-weight: 700;
                font-size: 19px;
                color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
            }
            .nav-link img {
                width: 25px;
                height: 25px;
            }
            .nav-active a {
                background: linear-gradient(90deg, #A2FACF 0%, #64ACFF 101.4%);
                -webkit-background-clip: text;
                -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
                background-clip: text;
                text-fill-color: transparent;
            }
            .nav-active {
                background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(162, 250, 207, 0.10) 0%, rgba(100, 172, 255, 0.1) 101.4%);
            }
        </style>
        {% block nav %}
       <div class="nav-container">
        <img src="{% static 'levelstatic/assets/coderalogo.svg' %}" style="margin: 0 auto;
        width: 80%; margin-bottom: 25px;" alt="CODERA">
            <div class="nav-links">
                <div class="nav-link nav-active">
                    <img src="{% static '/dashimages/learn.svg' %}" > 
                    <a>LEARN</a>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-link">
                    <img src="{% static '/dashimages/review.svg' %}" > 
                    <a>REVIEW</a>
                </div> 
                <div class="nav-link">
                    <img src="{% static '/dashimages/progress.svg' %}" > 
                    <a>PROGRESS</a>
                </div> 
                <div class="nav-link">
                    <img src="{% static '/dashimages/compete.svg' %}" > 
                    <a>COMPETE</a>
                </div> 
            </div>   
       </div>
       {% endblock%}
    </body>
</html>
```

When I extend `base.html` on my `dashboard.html`, I want to display the content (navbar) in the `base.html` as well as my other content.

I do this using the following code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block nav %}
{% endblock %}
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working. Nothing shows up, except a black screen and some styles I have in my `base.html`.

Does anyone have an idea as to why this is occuring? In case it has something to do with the rest of my code in my `dashboard.html`, I have provided that below.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load custom_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script defer data-domain="codera.app" src="https://plausible.io/js/script.js"></script> <!--PLAUSIBLE-->

        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        {% comment %} <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'dashboardstyle.css' %}"> {% endcomment %}
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
        <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700&family=Space+Grotesk:wght@500;700&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{% static 'levelstatic/assets/fav.ico' %}">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Gloria+Hallelujah&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.3/gsap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        {% comment %} <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'dashboardscript.js' %}" defer></script> {% endcomment %}
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script> 
        <title>Codera | Dashboard</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            html {
                scroll-behavior: smooth;
            }
            *,
            body {
                margin: 0;
            }
            body {
                display:flex; flex-direction:row;
                background: #030914;
                background: url('/static/dashimages/map.svg'), #030914;;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                overflow-y:scroll;
            }
            h1 {
                font-family: 'Space Grotesk';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 700;
                color:rgba(255,255,255, .90);
            }
           
        </style>
       {% block nav %}
       {% endblock %}

       
        <div class="maincontainer">
            <div class="leftcontent">
                <div class="levelscontainer">
                    {% comment %} <div class="chapter">
                        <h1>Unit 1</h1>
                        <p>learn all about this ....</p>
                    </div> {% endcomment %}
                    <div id="levels">
                       
                    </div>
                </div> 


                {% comment %} <div class="levelscontainer">
                    <div class="chapter">
                        <h1>Unit 1</h1>
                        <p>learn all about this ....</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="levels">
                        <div class="level">
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="level"></div>
                        <div class="level"></div>
                    </div>
                </div> {% endcomment %}


            </div>
            <div class="rightcontent">
                <div class="top">
                    <div class="points focus">
                        <img src="{% static '/dashimages/focusclock.svg' %}" style="width:20px; filter: invert(19%) sepia(1%) saturate(6780%) hue-rotate(187deg) brightness(88%) contrast(100%);"> 
                        <p>FOCUS</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="points">
                        <img src="{% static '/dashimages/medal.png' %}" style="width:20px;"> 
                        <p style="color:#F69C18;">{{medals}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="points">
                        <img src="{% static '/dashimages/fire.svg' %}" style="width:25px;"> 
                        <p style="color: #FFC001;">{{streaks}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="points">
                        <img src="{% static '/dashimages/diamond.png' %}" style="width:25px;"> 
                        <p style="color: #30E1B9;">{{diamonds}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bottom">
                    <div class="box">
                       <div class="message">
                        <img src="{% static '/dashimages/drvega.png' %}" style="width:70px; height: 70px;"> 
                        <div class="messagetitle">
                            <h1>Dr. Vega</h1>
                            <p>Incoming message</p>
                            <button>VIEW MESSAGE</button>
                        </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
          
</html>
```

Comment: your `dashboard.html` does not render: indeed you did not specify any `{% block ... %}`. Since it extends from `base.html`, it will only replace blocks, so everything below `{% load custom_tags %}` is ignored.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what do you mean? Do I need to include all my content in a `{% block content %}`?

Comment: @jahnathalla: there is no `{% block content %}` in the `base.html`. You can only override the `nav` block, so no that will not work.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Could you possibly structure your comment as an answer so that I can better understand what your saying? I tried wrapping it in a block content but it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Ended up figuring it out - have to include the `{% block content %}` in your base HTML file. When Django inherits from the base HTML file it searches for all of the blocks you have provided in the parent template and replaces them with the ones you have provided in the child template. So if you provide a block in the child template where it does not exist in the parent template it would do nothing. If you want to tell Django to include the h1 tag in the content block you have to place the `{% block content %}{% endblock %}` in the parent template so Django knows where to replace it.

For example you can put `{% block content %}{% endblock %}` like this:

```
{% load static %}
{% load custom_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        {% comment %} <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'dashboardscript.js' %}" defer></script> {% endcomment %}
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script> 
        <title>Codera | Dashboard</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      
        {% block nav %}
        <div class="nav-container">
         <img src="{% static 'levelstatic/assets/coderalogo.svg' %}" style="margin: 0 auto;
         width: 80%; margin-bottom: 25px;" alt="CODERA">
             <div class="nav-links">
                 <div class="nav-link nav-active">
                     <img src="{% static '/dashimages/learn.svg' %}" > 
                     <a>LEARN</a>
                 </div>
                 <div class="nav-link">
                     <img src="{% static '/dashimages/review.svg' %}" > 
                     <a>REVIEW</a>
                 </div> 
                 <div class="nav-link">
                     <img src="{% static '/dashimages/progress.svg' %}" > 
                     <a>PROGRESS</a>
                 </div> 
                 <div class="nav-link">
                     <img src="{% static '/dashimages/compete.svg' %}" > 
                     <a>COMPETE</a>
                 </div> 
             </div>
        </div>
        {% endblock %}

        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}

    </body>
        
</html>
```